# Azure Pipelines, remove certain characters from build number

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, clickonce, azure-pipelines-build-task, gitversion

We use `GitVersion` which in the `.yml` file has tag `alpha` for the develop branch. We also use `MSBuild` to make `ClickOnce` app and we want to use the `GitVersion` version for the app version. As far as I know `GitVersion` updates the build number, so in theory the version can be set with `/p:AssemblyVersion=${Build.BuildNumber}`, but the format of the version is `[major].[minor].[build]-{tag}.[revision]`, e.g. `2.1.0-alpha.5`.

Is it possible to set the `AssemblyVersion` to `2.1.0.5` so the build won't fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a simple script that removes the `-alpha` from the version and update the build number:

```
$buildNumber = $env:Build_BuildNumber
$version = $buildNumber -creplace '-.....', ''
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$version"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually updated `pipeline variable` rather than build number directly, but it works!

Comment: @Expressingx I was definitely debating what would you prefer... I'm glad I helped!